# why is the scroll position different browser/window mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, position

im using the following script to see what the position is of the scrollbar

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    jQuery('.scroll').html(document.body.scrollTop);
});

<div class="scroll"></div>
```

it just outputs the px of the position of the scroll in the div, but for some reason the position results are different all the time

like, when my window of my browser (chrome) is maxed and i scroll down the page it shows 1095px

when i dont have my window maximized and i scroll down it shows 1600px

when i open it in IE, its shows 1065px

so for some reason depending on the windowmode and browsertype i get different results when i want the calculate the position of the scrollbar

what am i doing wrong here?

ohh and i using the results with the following script.
if the scroll is at a certain position, show the div (thats the idea) and im searching for an script where i can set functions to diffent positions like
500px show menu
1000px show div
1200px show footerform
etc

```
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1000) {

    $('.showdiv').fadeIn(500);

  }
```

so if i cant calculate the position right, the script kinda doesnt work :)

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by scrollTop is that of the distance of the element is above the top of the rendered window.

```
   +-----------+     \
   |           |     |  - this distance.
+----------------- + /
|  |           |   |
|  |           |   |
|  +-----------+   |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

If you have a 1000px tall div, and your render window is 600px you will have 400px above the rendered edge. If you have a render window of 200px, there will be 800px above the rendered edge.

You can think of it as the distance you'd have to scroll back up to show the top of the element.

If you can see this effect by making your window small and then scroll down the page ~100px.

Now pull the bottom of the window down. You'll notice as soon as the scroll bar reaches the bottom of the page the value starts to decrease.

http://jsbin.com/ibefal/2

More Info: http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrolltop

Comment: well the problem with is, if i have my browserwindow maximed the variable goes to 1095px when i scroll to the bottom, when my browserwindow isnt maximed it goes t0 1600px when i scroll to the bottom so how do i make the following script working if(the-element-that-is-800px-from-top == visible in currentwindow) { $('#element').fadeIn(); } or should i use another function for that?